# Pass variable contents to class function in Python

Tags: python, class, variables, python-2.7

I'm trying to pass the contents of a variable to a function within a class that's run as a thread. How would I do this? Following is some pseudo code that should have the output following. The variable in question is `p_number`.

## Pseudo

```
class sessioning(Thread):    
    def run(self, p_number):
        print p_number    


p_number = 50885
for i in xrange(30):
    sessioning().start(p_number)         
    p_number+=1
```

## Wanted Output

```
50885
50886
50887
50888
50889
50890
50891
50892
50893
50894
50895
... Numbers in-between
50914
50915
```

Please note that this code is just an example, and I'm not actually performing overkill. This is a general question, but my specific application is to have it listen on ports within that range.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass it via constructor.

```
class Sessioning(Thread):
    def __init__(self, p_number):
         Thread.__init__(self)
         self._pn = p_number

    def run(self):
        print(self._pn)

p_number = 50885
for i in xrange(30):
    Sessioning(p_number).start()
    p_number += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The Thread class has already implemented an easy way for you to invoke a function with arguments.

Here's a simple example:

```
def say_hi(name):
    print "hello", name
```

Now you can use the Thread constructor to pass in the argument either by position or by name:

```
from threading import Thread
a = Thread(target=say_hi, args=("byposition",))
a.run()
b = Thread(target=say_hi, kwargs={"name": "byname"})
b.run()
```

This should correctly ouput:

```
hello byposition
hello byname
```

[Référence](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html)

Ps: as a side note, since you are using multithreading, you cannot assume that the output will come in order like you showed in the example.